# Can API redirect URLs can connect to a network protected by VPN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vpn, okta, okta-api

I am working on a web application. I am setting up a third-party service provider as an authentication provider (Okta). I have two applications.

Application 1:
This is a central app to many other applications where users visit this website and are redirected to Application 2 after validating credentials against a third-party authentication provider. in my case, I am using Okta for authentication. I set up the application 2 URL as a redirect URL for this app

Application 2:
This app is purely user content app it will check for sessions or cookies created by the Application 1 redirect URL.

This application working as expected in the local host, But not working after hosting in our DEV environment. Application 1 successfully validates user credentials and redirects with valid sessions to token to application 2. The required sessions are not created in application 2 through its redirect URL.

Our dev environments are protected by VPN.

I suspect this is due to our DEV environment URLS being VPN-protected.

Please suggest a way to troubleshoot to find the solution.

Startup.CS (Application 1)

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Login"),
            });

            app.UseOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions()
            {
                OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"],
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],
                AuthorizationServerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:AuthorizationServerId"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access" },
                LoginMode = LoginMode.SelfHosted,
            });
        }
        private void SetCookieAuthenticationAsDefault(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        }

        private void AddOktaAuthenticationMiddleware(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions()
            {
                OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"],
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
                Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email" },
            });
        }
```

Validation credentials and redirecting to other application 2

```
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                LoginModel objlogin = new LoginModel();
                objlogin.username = email;
                objlogin.password = password;

                // Validate user credentials in Okta
                OktaModel oktaApiResponse = oktaLoginBO.ValidateUser(username,password);


                // 1. If no errors occured while validating okta.
                // 2. If credentials are correct 
            
                 
                if (oktaApiResponse.status == true)
                {                   

                        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties();
                        properties.Dictionary.Add("sessionToken", oktaApiResponse.oktaAuthenticationResponse.sessionToken);
                        properties.Dictionary.Add("useremail", oktaApiResponse.oktaValidateUserResponseModel._embedded.user.profile.login);
                        properties.RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"].ToString();

                        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties,
                            OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationType);

                        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View("UnAuthorized");
                    }
                }

            }
```

I have tried different ways to read the okta sessions. application successfully connects to a third-party authentication provider and returns a valid session token. However, the required sessions are not created on redirect URLs. I don't find the root cause of this.

I want to know if this could be a reason because our URL is being protected by VPN.